# How to send multiple checkboxes in CodeIgniter via jQuery AJAX?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with my code why then i click buton simpan the respon in url :

output in url :

localhost/rootappl/moduls/krs myCheckboxes%5B%5D=KFT106&myCheckboxes%5B%5D=KFT107&submit=Simpan

HTML CODE :

[IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/21lpzk9.png[/IMG]

HTML Code :

```
<form id="input_krs" class="input_krs" method="post" name="input_krs" action="#"> 
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tabel" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
      <tr valign="middle" class="head" style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">
          <td width="2%"><center>No</center></td>
          <td width="12%"><center>KODEMK</center></td>
          <td><center>MATA KULIAH</center></td> 
          <td><center>SKS</center></td>
          <td><center>Jadwal</center></td>  
          <td><center>Aksi<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="select_all"></center></td>  
          </tr> 
          <tr>
            <td align="center">1</td>
            <td align="center">KFT106</td>
            <td>MATEMATIKA DASAR I</td>
            <td align="center">3</td>
            <td>RABU, Jam:10.15, Kelas:A, Ruang:207 Astri Charolina, S.KOM</td>
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" id="myCheckboxes" value="KFT106" class="checkbox"></td>
          </tr> 
          <tr>
            <td align="center">1</td>
            <td align="center">KFT107</td>
            <td>MATEMATIKA DASAR I</td>
            <td align="center">3</td>
            <td>RABU, Jam:10.15, Kelas:A, Ruang:207 Astri Charolina, S.KOM</td>
       <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" id="myCheckboxes" value="KFT107" class="checkbox"></td>
            </tr>  
          <tr>            
          <td colspan="6" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>  
      </tbody>
      <br>  
    </table>
    </form> 

<div class="box-footer">
<tr>         
      <td align="center">
     <center>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Simpan" onclick="submitForm()" /> </center></td>
  </tr> 
<br>   
</div>
```

respon :

```
 <div id="myResponse"></div>
```

Jquery ajax code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">   

$(document).ready(function(){  

function submitForm() { 
var form = document.myform;
var dataString = $(form).serialize();    
$.ajax({    
    type:'POST', 
    url  : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>krs/save",
    data: 'dataString',
     // data: {dataString : dataString},
    success: function(data){
        $('#myResponse').html(data);
        console.log(dataString);
        alert(" Hello! I am an alert box!! ");
    },
        'error': function(response) {
             //echo 'error 1 ';
        }
});
return false;
} 
}); 
</script>
```

print log :

```
 <?php 

    echo var_export($_POST);

    ?>
```

Contoller :

```
<?php
  public function save()
  {
      $x =  $this->input->post('myCheckboxes');
      printr($x);
  }
?>
```

can help me ?

Br, Thanks.

Comment: Can help me please ...

Comment: anyone, can help me please ?

Comment: what you want only checkboxes values?

Comment: Give your html as code here not in image

Comment: @AnandPandey, done

Answer (score 0):

please check this code and let me know its working or not? You are take id same on two inputs which is wrong. First you have to see what the data is get from ajax on ci by $_POST. **I remove the function call from the submit button.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#input_krs').on('submit', function(e) {
    var dataString = $('#input_krs').serializeArray();   
    $.ajax({    
        type:'POST', 
        url  : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>krs/save",
        data: {sendval: dataString },
         // data: {dataString : dataString},
        success: function(data){
            $('#myResponse').html(data);
        },
        'error': function(response) {
             //echo 'error 1 ';
        }
    });
  });
}); 
</script>
```

In the controller KRK

```
<?php
  public function save()
  {
      if($_POST){
        print_r($_POST);
        $x =  $this->input->post('sendval');
        echo "<pre>";print_r($x); die;
      }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Not work, the action in the ouput the same in url : http://localhost/rootapp/controllers/krs?myCheckboxes%5B%5D=KFT106&myCheckboxes%5B%5D=KFT107&submit=Simpan

Comment: I have edit my answer. First of all you see that data is coming or not from ajax so use print_r($_POST); in save function.

Comment: not solved, the same problem, the page cannot redirect to controller : krs/save. the code nothing print_r($_POST), the page the same problem @Anand Pandey

Comment: It means error is in your controller or route. Give full controller code here.

Comment: my controller is your code share, in my appl is hmvc ..this is the image hmvc module

Comment: I try the code like this :  
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 
 
  $('#input_krs').on('submit', function(e) {
  
     alert(" Hello! I am an alert box!! ");
 
  });
}); 
</script>.... the alert not working ? @Anand Pandey..

Comment: It means even your jquery is not working. Please include jquery in header.

Answer (score 0):

my controller code :

```
public function save(){
        //$x =  $this->input->post('myCheckboxes');
        //printr($x);



        //$rows =  $this->input->post('rows');
        //foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
        //  $arr =  array(
        //      'id_mahasiswa'=>$value['mhs'],
        //      'id_kurikulum'=>$value['kurikulum'],
        //      'krs_create_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        //  );
        //  $this->general->save($arr,'tt_krs');
        //}

        if($_POST){
        print_r($_POST);
        $x =  $this->input->post('sendval');
        echo "<pre>";print_r($x); die;
      }
```

[Image HMVC Root appl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2uEQ.png)

https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=21810643520